# While doing selenium, how to do enter key action, on a search bar which has no search button

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I've been trying to test an ecommerce site after I close the initial popup no elements is captured by

```
bd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div/span")).click();
```

So, I have been using

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)bd;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

And after a while I got stuck at a place where I have to do the enter key action. I have been trying various keys for this and none of them seems to work. So, I either need a code for using the enter button event on the search bar using `JavascriptExecutor` or a solution where I can fetch elements using `findElement`.

Comment: I have edited your question. Please check if I did it wrong. You, of course, can edit it too.

Comment: @Theraot I am new here, so if the question is changed to a much more understandable form, that is ofcource appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't know much about selenium, but my first guess would be that the path is wrong. And about the enter key action, something like this: [creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). Perhaps a [keyboard event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) or an [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). Anyway, hopefully people more familiar with the topic will post an answer.

Comment: I ll just wait then.

Answer (score 0):

To enter the text within the search field you can use the following solution:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'valueToEnter';", webelement);
```

Comment: I need a code to trigger the enter button event. not eter values.